# How to create folders based on search string in a file name and move files into it?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code with the help of some wonderful people/experts to transfer files based on part of its name into static folders.

```
*Move 0001_ddmmyy_username[active1]_L_kkkkk.pdf to C:\Users\abc\London
Move 0001_ddmmyy_jacky[active1]_R_kkkkk.pdf to C:\Users\abc\Russia
Move 0001_ddmmyy_jim[active1]_P_kkkkk.pdf to C:\Users\abc\Poland*
```

Change $env:userprofile\desktop. Remove -whatif when you are satisfied it works.

```
$items = gci -recurse -file *_L_*, *_R*, *_P*
foreach($item in $items) {
  # Change $env:userprofile\desktop
  if($item -like "*_L_*") {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item "$env:userprofile\desktop\London"
  } elseif($item -like "*_R_*") {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item "$env:userprofile\desktop\Russia" 
  } elseif ($item -like '*_P_*') {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item "$env:userprofile\desktop\Poland" 
  }
}
```

However, I would like some improvement.

I have a folder structure like:

1. Mainfolder **BOX**
2. Subfolder  **ITEM** *(the name is not of any fixed format or string length Eg: ITEM1, ITEM188, ITEM101, etc)*
3. Within ITEM code folder there are many folders with many pdf files in it.
4. Based on the part of pdf file name which are _L,_R,_P etc., the  files have to be **moved** by creating folders by checking if the folder/files exist and if yes ask once and replace it all one shot
   eg: Within BOX>> there are ITEM1, ITEM188, ITEM101 and so on >> Within each of them there are folders called ISSUE1, ISSUE2, ISSUE3 and so on >> within each there are pdf files 0001_ddmmyy_username[active1]_L_kkkkk.pdf, 0001_ddmmyy_username[active1]_R_kkkkk.pdf, 0001_ddmmyy_username[active1]_P_kkkkk.pdf and so on.
5. If I run the powershell script in ITEM code folder, it should create folders >> London, Russia, Poland and move _L to London, _R files to Russia, _P to Polland and so on.

Search Criteria
    $items = gci -recurse -file *L_*, *_R*, *_P*, *and so on*
    Folders to be created based on the search items if _L move to folder London (which has to be created), _R folder to create is Russia (which has to be created)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: what is the path to all of the box*?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `New-Item` cmdlet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7

When using the `-Force` parameter, it will create any intermediate directories without removing any contents of existing folders.

Combining that with a check to see if it exists with `Test-Path`, we have the following code:

```bsh
$items = gci -recurse -file *_L_*, *_R*, *_P*
foreach($item in $items) {
  # Change $env:userprofile\desktop
  if($item -like "*_L_*") {
    # Define full folder path
    $desiredPath = "$env:userprofile\some\extra\long\custom\folder\structure\London"
    # If full folder strucure does not exist, create it
    if(!(Test-Path $desiredPath)) {
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $desiredPath
    }
    # Move the item into the new folder
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item $desiredPath
  } elseif($item -like "*_R_*") {
    $desiredPath = "$env:userprofile\another\folder\structure\Russia" 
    if(!(Test-Path $desiredPath)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $desiredPath
    }
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item $desiredPath
  } elseif ($item -like '*_P_*') {
    $desiredPath = "$env:userprofile\some\other\folder\structure\Poland"
    if(!(Test-Path $desiredPath)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $desiredPath
    }
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $item $desiredPath
  }
}
```

If you don't want output when it creates the folders, you can either pipe to `Out-Null` or push directly into `$null`:

```bsh
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $desiredPath | Out-Null
```

OR

```bsh
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $desiredPath > $null
```

Comment: Hi RetryW, 
This does not make any output. Do I need to change anything at the path after $env:. Ideally it should take the current path from the first gci command and then join the London folder to it and the come out and then join the Russia and Poland folder accordingly. However, this does not generate any output.

Comment: @CuriousEngineer hey mate. The `$desiredPath` string I have in there are just as an example of how you can have a full folder path get created without needing to create the folders in-between.  Replace it with `"$env:userprofile\desktop\London"` or whatever your actual desired path is.

Comment: I dont want to specify or hardcode the directory in the desired path. It should take it from current directory + the newly created folder

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.

Move `box\item*\issue*\*_L_*.pdf` to `box\item*\London` using PowerShell gci, foreach, if $item -like, -split, if not test-path new-item directory, -whatif, and move-item.

Change `$HOME\Desktop\box` : Remove `-whatif`

```
pushd "$HOME\Desktop\box"
$items = gci -recurse -file *_L_*, *_R_*, *_P_*
foreach($item in $items) {
if($item -like "*_L_*") {
# begin path to folder called item to variable $zitem 
$zitem,$b = "$item" -split "\\issue"
#   end path to folder called item to variable $zitem  
if(!(Test-Path $zitem\London)) {
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $zitem\London -whatif | out-null
}
Move-Item -LiteralPath $item "$zitem\London" -whatif | out-null
} elseif($item -like "*_R_*") {
$zitem,$b = "$item" -split "\\issue"
if(!(Test-Path $zitem\Russia)) {
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $zitem\Russia -whatif | out-null
}
Move-Item -LiteralPath $item "$zitem\Russia" -whatif | out-null
} elseif ($item -like '*_P_*') {
$zitem,$b = "$item" -split "\\issue"
if(!(Test-Path $zitem\Poland)) {
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $zitem\Poland -whatif | out-null
}
Move-Item -LiteralPath $item "$zitem\Poland" -whatif | out-null
}}
popd
```

Comment: 1. Move box/item*/issue*/*_L_*.pdf to box/item*/issue*/London is wrong. Instead it should be Move box/item*/issue*/*_L_*.pdf to box/item*/London
2. Is it possible to do it without specifying the path. So example if I run in the folder box1/item1/issue1 can it automatically take the path and do the necessary. 
3. Current code creates folders in C: eg C:/London and moved _L_ pdf files into it.. similarly for the others too

Comment: look at your answer above, I copied it from there. 

Comment: The path of box will keep changing. I would need to get it dynamically. I wish to run the code in any box folder and it should take the path from where I execute the script. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: give three examples of the box path.